# Node-schedule monthly call

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

Does this function run only once a month at 12

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
 var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
 rule.month = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
 rule.hour = 12;
 rule.minute = 0;
 const handleMonthyFunction = () => console.log("Monthly");
 var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, handleMonthyFunction);
```

Comment: If you are not sure then you can try the same scheduling with minutes and seconds. Instead `rule.month` do `rule.minute` and same for `rule.hour`, change it with `rule.second` and see if it really works that way.

Comment: You would need to set the date as well. As per it's description : `Node Schedule is for time-based scheduling, not interval-based scheduling.`